# Defining IBOutlet attributes in extension

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, ios7, interface-builder

I have a view controller that started to be too big, so I decided to move all buttons functionality to a separate extension.

```
//MyViewController.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@end

//MyViewController+Buttons.h
@interface MyViewController (Buttons)

- (void)adjustButtons;

@end

//MyViewController+Buttons.m
@interface MyViewController ()
{

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

@end

@implementation MyViewController(Buttons)

@end
```

Interface builder lets me bind the button to the outlet but when I run the app I receive the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyViewController 0x12e501a70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myButton
```

I know that it should be possible to define outlets in an extensions of the view controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could also just put your outlets in the class extension within the .m file. That way you don't have everything available in the header file and your code can look cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring an interface but you're not providing an implementation.  (If you change your IBOutlet to an ivar instead of a property, you'll get a linker error instead of a runtime error.)

In order for a property and ivar to be automatically synthesized, its declaration needs to be visible from its compilation unit (typically, "MyViewController.m").

In your case, move the `@interface MyViewController()` declaration to "MyViewController+Buttons.h", and import that header in "MyViewController.m"